# Transfer Account owner without changing opportunity owner

Tags: opportunity, account

Is there a way I can change the account owner without having the related open opportunities owner being changed?

Comment: i think you can setup a flow to handle this scenario

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_owner_transfer.htm&type=5) states,

> The account owner’s open opportunities are transferred automatically.

The only workaround is to write automation to detect when an account owner is changed and change all open opportunities back to the original owner.

Comment: thanks for this David. Would you happen to have any resources as to how i could go about doing this? much appreciated

Comment: You should be able to do this with Flow.  Check Salesforce Trailhead and other web resources for tutorials on Flow.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one off exercise to transfer ownership of several Accounts at once:

If you transfer Opportunity Ownership using an external data loader instead of 'Mass Transfer Accounts' in the setup menu, then the Opportunities will not change Owner too.

To do this, I would:

1. Download a list of Accounts for transfer, making sure to include the RecordId and OwnerId fields.
2. Open in a spreadsheet: Update the OwnerIds to match who you want the new Owner to be.
   Depending on whether you have one new owner or many, I might do this manually or using VLookup to a list of User Records to find the correct User record ID.
   Save the updated file!
3. Go to your dataloader of choice. I like dataloader.io
   Use it to import your updated Accounts, mapping the RecordId and OwnerId fields.
   Make sure to select that you are UPDATING records, otherwise you risk creating duplicates.

Having done this, you should have Accounts with new owners but the Opportunity owners won't have changed.

Unfortunately, this isn't really convenient if you need to do it daily. Unless you teach your users to use a dataloader!